# delete duplicates in a table and update references

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with `id`, we now added a new field where we calculated uniques from an external source, which made us realize we actually have duplicates in the database:

**Main Table**

```
id | unique_id | ...
---|------------
4  | A         |
5  | A
6  | B
```

We can see: `5` is actually a duplicate of `4`, as they both have the same `unique_id`.

Now this needs to be cleaned up.

I sadly can not simply delete those duplicates (`5`), as other tables depend on it:

**Other Table** (`OtherTable.main_id REFERENCES MainTable.id`)

```
id | main_id | ...
---|------------
1  | 4       | Blah
2  | 5
3  | 6
```

Now I have to clean up the duplicates, here

```sql
UPDATE OtherTable SET main_id = 5 WHERE main_id=4
```

How can I do that in an efficient update?
I tried to simply update every reference to the first one with that same `unique_id`, however that didn't complete in a day.

```sql
UPDATE "OtherTable" SET "main_id" = (SELECT "id" FROM "MainTable" WHERE "unique_id" = (SELECT "unique_id" FROM "MainTable" WHERE "id" == "OtherTable"."main_id") LIMIT 1)
```

If it helps, the `MainTable` contains about 750,000 entries, the `OtherTable` contains 12,000,000 rows.

Probably that's because those tripple select one is quite inefficient.

For the simple part of deletion the duplicates (after I would be done with changing the references to the first one of it's kind) I found this query to work swiftly enough:

```sql
DELETE FROM MainTable
    WHERE id IN
        (SELECT id
        FROM
            (SELECT id,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY unique_id
            ORDER BY  id ) AS row_num
            FROM MainTable ) t
            WHERE t.row_num > 1 );
```

However I need a way to update the references to the non-deleted ones of the duplicates.

Comment: Please dont confuse UPDATE and DELETE. What do you want?

Comment: @wildplasser UPDATE all the tables referencing the duplicates, and then DELETE the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `UPDATE` with a nested query, I'd suggest using [`UPDATE FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) for a join, and the same window function as in your `DELETE` statement:

```
UPDATE "OtherTable" AS other
SET main_id = main.min_id
FROM (SELECT
    id,
    first_value(id) OVER (PARTITION BY unique_id ORDER BY id) AS min_id
  FROM "MainTable"
) AS main
WHERE main.id = other.main_id
  AND main.id <> main.min_id
```